# Extracting Format of Tutorial Notebook

Tags: notebooks, formatting, documentation

I noticed that the documentation contains some beautifully formatted notebooks which I would like to use for my file. However, simply copying the cells does not work. So how can I get the formats of such files, for example, the header, main paragraph, latex display, etc. shown in this screenshot? This file is located at SystemFiles\Components\PDEModels\PDEModels\Documentation\Tutorials\MassTransport\ModelCollection.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a new "Tech Note" from the documentation tools palette. There was a tech talk on this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2q3e-QIZMA

If you just want to tweak that notebook, this might do the trick for you:

```
fn = "/Library/Wolfram/Documentation/13.0/en-us/Documentation/English/Paclets/PDEModels/Tutorials/MassTransport/ModelCollection/CatalystDeactivation.nb";
nb = NotebookPut[Import@fn];
sd = Insert[CurrentValue[nb,StyleDefinitions],
       Cell[StyleData[All], Saveable->True, Editable->True, Deletable->True], {1,1}];
SetOptions[nb,StyleDefinitions->sd]
```

Comment: Thanks! How about the references part? Is that italic styling and linking completely manual?

Comment: I think that's manual, it's just an ItemNumbered cell. Were you able to try using the "Documentation Tools" paclet?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems that all modifications to that generated notebook cannot be saved.  Why?

Comment: Now it should be...